# How to connect to raspberry pi on ubuntu

Tags: ssh, ethernet

I cannot seem to get an ethernet connection to the raspberry pi from ubuntu. It does not find the pi on ifconfig. The ip address of the raspberry pi is static, so should be 192.168.1.23. When I ping to it I get a response, but when I attempt to ssh connect I get:

"ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.23 port 22: Connection refused"

Any advice on how to connect please?

Answer (score 1):

You have an Ethernet connection.  If you didn't the ping would not work.

You don't say how you have enabled the SSH server on the Pi.

If you haven't you could enable the SSH server by one of the following methods.

- If you can login then run raspi-config (`sudo raspi-config`)
- If you have an SD card reader in your Ubuntu box insert the Pi's SD card and create an empty file called `ssh` in the boot partition (the small FAT partition on the SD card).

Comment: The raspberry pi has compiled code on it. I wish to take the data off using a tcip connection. I have managed this task before but it has stopped working. SSH is enabled, but does not seem to work

Comment: @Sam You need to edit your question and add all relevant information.

Comment: ssh is not enabled(or not configured), hence the connection refused message.  This means the port is open, the pi is online, but there is nothing that wants to accept the connection.